# htaccess laravel quitar www y poner / al final

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy intentando en mi laravel 5.8 hacer que todas mis rutas acaben con / y también que quite las www. del principio de la URL. los de las www creo que lo he conseguido de esta manera:

```
# drop www in url
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Pero no consigo hacer que ponga la `/` al final de mi url. Por lo que he leido Laravel por defecto la elimina porque entiende que es un directorio. Pero me gustaría forzar a que se ponga, para el SEO

Estoy intentando ponerla de esta forma:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Pero sin éxito.

**Actualizacion**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # drop www in url
    # www.guiapaladar.com
    # RewriteEngine on
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.guiapaladar.com [NC] 
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://guiapaladar.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Force Trailing Slash
    # RewriteBase /
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

gracias de antemano y un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Forzar www

Puedes añadir el siguiente código

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Esto forzará las "www." en las peticiones al dominio, si necesitas borrar las "www." del dominio puedes usar

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Ajusta el código al dominio que necesites borrar o añadir las "www."

### Añadir "/" al final de la URL

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Esto forzará al navegador a poner la "/" al final de la URL. Si es causa de un error en el sitio puedes usar javascript

```
if (location.href.toString().replace(location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname, "").charAt(0) !== "/") {
  location.replace(location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + "/";
}
```

#### Puede ser de utilidad

- [Forzar HTTPS con htaccess](https://www.34sp.com/kb/152/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file)
- [Añadir "/" al final de la URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end)
- [Forzar las www](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/force-www-htaccess/)

### EDIT

Si necesitas excluir "/" de archivos con extenciones específicas puedes usar

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css|js|ts|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Esto excluirá la barra "/" al final de la URL a archivos con extensión:

- .php
- .html
- .css
- .js

...

### Edit 2

Prueba a cambiar tu htaccess con esto

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css|js|ts|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTPS_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, es de gran ayuda. Pero tengo un problema y es que por ejemplo para cargar este recurso: (index):14 GET http://guiapaladar.local/web/css/plugins.css net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS da en consola ese problema y no cargan los estilos. En mis rutas, he visto que pone la barra al final, pero parece que laravel lo entiende como directorio o no lo se y en el navegador aparece esto ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Limpia lo que pusiste en tu htaccess, luego quita las www con el segundo bloque de código en el post, el problema debe estar solucionado, además no sería conveniente poner "/" al final ya que por ejemplo un archivo lo interpretaría como un directorio y tiraría un error 404, entonces se añade el "/" al final de la página y vuelve a redirigir lo que crea redirecciones infinitas, de ahí el error TOO_MANY_REDITECTS. Encontré una solución oportuna, déjame editar la respuesta, por favor.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @anythingg he actualizado mi pregunta con mi htaccess actual. Tengo un subdominio de pruebas, donde voy viendo si todos los cambios están correctos antes de pasar a produccion. como podría hacer que funcionaran los cambios ahí también¿?? el subdominio empieza por dev. y ahora mismo con lo que tengo hecho se me va a la url esta: /var/www/vhosts/ por delante mi dominio y por detras igual....

Comment: Deberías crear un htaccess en el directorio del subdominio, debes ser cuidadoso para no causar un conflicto con el htaccess principal, ejemplo: si el htaccess principal tiene redirección a HTTPS, no pongas la misma redirección en el htaccess del subdominio

Comment: gracias por tus respuestas. Yo es que no tengo acceso al htaccess del subdominio, por eso me gustaría restaurar para que se volviera a ver. como podría arreglarlo¿??

Comment: esta sería la url que me está generando https://dev.guiapaladar.com/var/www/vhosts/guiapaladar.com/dev.guiapaladar.com/%5e/ pero solo necesito que entre a http://dev.guiapaladar.com

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, el htaccess principal puede modificar también al del subdominio si ambos se encuentran en el mismo directorio, ejemplo: Root: public_html, sub: public_html/sub

Comment: Estás redirigiendo desde el subdominio hacia un directorio, con el script para el "/" esto creará un TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: donde estoy haciendo eso¿?? perdona mi ignorancia, pero no he modificado muchas veces el htacess ni se como funciona muy bien

Comment: Si cambias tu htaccess con el bloque en el edit 2 ¿deja de reportar ese error?